# How do I get HMR working with React, Next.js and Typescript in this template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I downloaded a template to use for my website ([GitHub](https://github.com/NextJSTemplates/startup-nextjs)), but when I try my local development environment using NPM, HMR doesn't work.

Here's what I do now:

`npm run build`

`npm run start`

The application will start and I'll try to make changes to the React components, but the changes are not reflected unless I rerun both those commands (which takes about a minute).

I checked my Next.js version, it's up to date. My understanding is that HMR should be enabled by default, but it clearly isn't working. I opened an issue with the repo I copied it from, but no response yet.

Comment: Took a look at the repository and saw that you [already opened an issue](https://github.com/NextJSTemplates/startup-nextjs/issues/7). Wait until the maintainer gets in touch with you since it is hard to reproduce without your version of the repo or any context.